# Python-Blender: Difference between ShaderNodes and Texture(ID)

Tags: python, texturing, shader-nodes

I am trying to understand how to add textures onto objects via python code. (I'm also a total beginner to Blender)

After long googling I have found that using "ShaderNodeTexVoronoi" creates a new node which I can even link (and unlink) to my material via the following code snippet:

```
# Get the first material
mat = bpy.data.materials[0]
# Get the nodes in the node tree
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
# Create the Shader Node
tex = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeTexVoronoi')

# Get a principled node
principled = next(n for n in nodes if n.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED')

# Add Link Between Shader and Principled BSDF
my_link = node_tree.links.new(tex.outputs['Color'],principled.inputs['Base Color'])

# Remove this link
node_tree.links.remove(my_link)
```

Now I also found the "texture" option which seems to have similar options via the following code:

```
# Create the texture
# More info under https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Texture.html
new_tex = bpy.data.textures.new("My texture", 'VORONOI')
```

There are a few videos (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqX5wh4YeRw ) where they use this line of code, but I'm not able to recreate the same results as I did with 'ShaderNodeTexVoronoi; above. In particular, they don't explain how you can link a texture-object (like new_tex) to a ShaderNode etc.

If anyone could provide me with more context or a tutorial/documentation where I can read more upon this than only the API that would be great. Unfortunately, I haven't found something useful.

Documentation on the API:

1. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNode.html#bpy.types.ShaderNode
2. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Texture.html

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can link a Texture object to a shader node. bpy.types.Textures are "legacy" textures that used to be used in materials before 2.80, but now are only used in a few odd places (eg. particle settings). They're supposed to get replaced at some point. Why do you want to use a bpy.types.Texture?

Comment: I don't have a real reason to use them. I had no idea they were legacy textures from older versions.

I just thought bpy.types.Textures are the correct way to handle those.